# tools available for generating wsdl from java interface(java2wsdl) in webservice

Tags: java, web-services

Generating java files(stubs and skeletons) from wsdl(wsdl2java) is quite easy but I felt that generating wsdl from java(java2wsdl) is not as easy as wsdl2java.

I am starting with a webservice from scratch, I have written the java interface which contains all the web service API.
I want to generate wsdl from my java interface, I have come across about apache axis.
It is good but I want to know that what are the other tools available to generate wsdl from java interface, which are friendly to implement and what are advantages and disadvantages of them.

Suggestions and opinions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `Apache Axis (v1.x and v2.x)`, I have used the `IBM JAX-RPC` implementation, some `JAX-WS` stuff and `Spring-WS` v2. My best experience thus far has been with the Spring framework. It advocates a contract-first development approach to web services; that is, create your `XML Schema` document first and then generate Java POJOs from that. Using `Spring-WS` you don't need to worry about creating a `WSDL` because (if you instruct it to) it will generate the `WSDL` based on your `XML Schema` document(s) and your configuration.

This allowed me to keep my `web service` `interface` packages nice and tidy: simple `annotations` hooked my `Java classes` into my Spring `configuration`, and the `Spring-WS` `framework` handled everything else. `Spring-WS` was the least `invasive framework` I've used for this, and also the easiest to get up and running with.

Comment: This is not exactly i was looking for but still it was informative so accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Web Service plugin for eclipse IDE: Press 'Ctrl+N ', and go to Web Service/Web Service. For the service implementation written, wsdl will get generated in the same project directory.

This is an easy way of generating wsdl and vice versa(client stubs).

Answer (score 0):

java2wsdl cmd available in apache cxf(For the cxf 2.1 versions, use java2ws instead) can do what exactly you want